# Passing C# value to JavaScript using Page.ClientScript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a personalizable value in C#

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User),
 WebBrowsable(true),
 WebDisplayName("Tab Display time"),
 WebDescription("Stand time for each tab in seconds"),
 Category("Custom Carousel Properties")]
 public int TimeToStand { get; set; }
```

I am trying to pass the variable 'TimeToStand' to a JavaScript function using Page.ClientScript

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", "<script type=text/javascript> newfunc(TimeToStand); </script>");            
        }
```

But, the value does not look to be passing as required.

The JavaScript function is as below:

```
function newfunc(timeToStand)
{
    alert(timeToStand);
}
```

Please advise if I am missing something.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting it as a part of string so all you get is not the value of your variable `TimeToStand` instead the string representation of variable name, Instead try this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", "<script type=text/javascript> newfunc(" + TimeToStand + "); </script>");
```

Comment: you just answered 30 seconds ahead of me.

better luck for me next time.

Comment: Thanks both @SidM and PSL. I could not +1 as I do not have enough reputation here

Comment: @Sagarika: can you plzz tick PSL answer as he answered the right answer first.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", "<script type=text/javascript> newfunc("+TimeToStand+"); </script>");
```